# .NET Core Configuration is forcing me to DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to read appsettings.json  non-controller class.Consider has a DatabaseUtil and contain a static connect() method. I need to connectionString for connection and i'm getting this from appsettings.json.This operation piece of cake in the startup.cs:)
Like this:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireDBConn")
```

Also it can be at the controller side with dependcy injection.But my problem which want to reach appSettings from DatbaseUtil class.
appSettings.json:

```
"NotifySettings": {
        "DbConnection": "abc",
        "Email": "abc@domain.com",
        "SMTPPort": "5605"
    }
```

Then i created my configuration settings class:

```
 public class NotifySettings 
    {
        public string DbConnection { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string SMTPPort { get; set; }
    }
```

And I added dependency for constructor injection to `DatabaseUtil` class and added `IDatabaseUtil`

```
public  class DatabaseUtil : IDatabaseUtil
    {
        private static NotifySettings _NotifySettings;

        public DatabaseUtil(IConfiguration _iconfig)
        {
            _NotifySettings = _iconfig.GetSection("NotifySettings").Get<NotifySettings>();
        }
        public static String ConnectToDatabase()
        {
            return "MESSAGE :" + _NotifySettings.DbConnection; 
        }

    }
}
```

And i added DatabaseUtil  to startup.cs

```
 services.AddScoped<IDatabaseUtil, DatabaseUtil>();
```

and finally i injected IDatabaseUtil to my controller class and  i can reach mysettings end of the this work.
Yes i can but not best way!

Let the join my  Brain Storming :) ; If i have to inject to IDatabaseUtil  every class where i want to use db helper methods.But if i had a static method in this class just it need to this line of code:

```
DatabaseUtils.connect();
```

That's feels me like i wrote unnecessary code.

What do you think about my approximation.Which one is best way for this case ?

Comment: Hi Onur: As written, this is largely a subjective comment without a problem to be solved, as there's not any real context of what your "case" is other than describing dependency injection versus static instances. Is there a specific question about DI? Check out [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If you have static data access methods, then you wrote unnecessary code - drop it.  Use this code only when you decide to abstract database methods.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback @AdamG Actually my problem is about approximations, little bit nice to have questions.But if you expect real problem question it could be this: How can i reach appsettings.json file from my DatabaseUtil class which have static helper method(I want touse settings model i know other type solutions).

Comment: @Fabio  if i drop this i cant reach appsettings.json with my settings model.This structure is forcing to me DI and thats the poin

Answer (score 0):

change

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseUtil, DatabaseUtil>();
```

to

```
services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseUtil, DatabaseUtil>();
```

This way you only have one instance of DatabaseUtil

Comment: Thank you Arun but this  is not related my problems solution.But it helped to me about learning something

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely clear, but if the need here is to make values from your Configuration statically available, then copy them from your configuration to a static class during the startup:

```
public static class GlobalSettings 
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        GlobalSettings.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you need to get the config and do the assignment from somewhere else, use the `ConfigurationBuilder`:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
```

Comment: (or, consider embracing dependency injection and the abstraction!)

Comment: it looks you understand to me nicely but i want say again  want to use settingmodel like this:                                                    
             public class NotifySettings 
    {
        public string DbConnection { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string SMTPPort { get; set; }
    }

Comment: If you want the full model, then change the string to your settings and bind the full model instead. 
`NotifySettings settings = new NotifySettings(); Configuration.GetSection("NotifySettings").Bind(settings);
        GlobalSettings.NotifySettings = settings;`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace project.Utility
{
    public class ConnectionString
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;
        private static ConnectionString _internalInstance;

        public static ConnectionString Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _internalInstance;
            }
        }

        public static void Init(IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _internalInstance = new ConnectionString();
            _internalInstance._config = config;
        }

        public String Get(string key)
        {

         var NotifySettings = 
                Instance._config.GetSection(key).Get<NotifySettings>();;
            return NotifySettings;
        }
    }
}

// call this above method from any place like controller or class file by below code 
// use refernece of the namespace
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(); // object creation
NotifySettings settings = connectionString.Get("NotifySettings"); // call with your key value  get the settings object
```

Try this it should work let me know if any issues i can help on that